# How to find record between two different year and month?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm try to find record between 2 different year and month but my query is not working. This is my query:

```
SELECT product_class.sublevel AS producttype, COUNT(*) AS totalclass
FROM vtiger_classes
    INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_classes.classesid AND vtiger_crmentity.deleted = 0
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT vtiger_product.productid, vtiger_product.sublevel_1 FROM vtiger_product
     INNER JOIN vtiger_crmentity ON vtiger_crmentity.crmid = vtiger_product.productid AND vtiger_crmentity.deleted = 0) AS product_class
     ON product_class.productid = vtiger_classes.Product
WHERE 1 BETWEEN MONTH(vtiger_classes.start_date) and MONTH(vtiger_classes.end_date)
AND 2019 BETWEEN YEAR(vtiger_classes.start_date) and YEAR(vtiger_classes.end_date)
GROUP BY product_class.sublevel
```

Comment: ONLY when the dates are the dates you mentioned? Or on all of their formats? And what do you mean by not working? What errors do you get? Programming questions needs to be more specific.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Try to use `STR_TO_DATE()` maybe to create the different date and just do `WHERE date BETWEEN date_min and date_max`

Comment: For a working answer you should include your table definitions and sample data as text in the question.

Comment: If your code is only supposed to select jan 2019 I would dispute that it isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

To get for example all orders from 2017-JAN until including 2018-DEC:

```
WHERE order_date >= CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE)
AND order_date < CAST('2019-01-01' AS DATE);
```

Or:

```
WHERE order_date >= CAST('2017-01-01' AS DATE)
AND order_date <= CAST('2018-12-31' AS DATE);
```

Comment: Assuming order_date is a date column (and not a string, dateime,timestamp ,integer etc)

Answer (score 0):

A simplified version of your data and code;-

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int auto_increment primary key, start_dt date, end_dt date);
insert into t (start_dt,end_dt) values
('2018-10-01','2019-03-01'),
('2018-12-31','2019-03-01'),
('2019-01-01','2019-03-01'),
('2019-01-01','2019-02-01'),
('2019-02-28','2019-03-01');

select t.*
from t
where 1 BETWEEN MONTH(start_dt) and MONTH(end_dt)
AND 2019 BETWEEN YEAR(start_dt) and YEAR(end_dt) ;
```

result

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | start_dt   | end_dt     |
+----+------------+------------+
|  3 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-03-01 |
|  4 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-01 |
+----+------------+------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Which is as expected (and works)

Changing the code to use dates

```
select t.*
from t
where (start_dt between '2018-12-31' and '2019-03-01') and
        (end_dt between '2018-12-31' and '2019-03-01');
```

result

```
+----+------------+------------+
| id | start_dt   | end_dt     |
+----+------------+------------+
|  2 | 2018-12-31 | 2019-03-01 |
|  3 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-03-01 |
|  4 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-02-01 |
|  5 | 2019-02-28 | 2019-03-01 |
+----+------------+------------+
```